# Ninguna de las extensiones PHP soportadas (MySQLi, MySQL, PDO_MySQL) está disponible

Tags: php, mysql, windows, wamp, php-5.6

Actualice mi pc con las ultimas actualizaciones de Windows 10, uso wamp, pero ahora al intentar acceder al adminer y a mis proyectos del localhost sale el siguiente mensaje:

Ninguna de las extensiones PHP soportadas (MySQLi, MySQL, PDO_MySQL) está disponible.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los archivos están en la carpeta correspondiente (C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext), en el php.ini no están comentados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uso PHP 5.6.25, pero al cambiar a PHP 7.2.28 si funciona. Mis proyectos están con PHP 5 y symfony por lo tanto no puedo usar PHP 7. Gracias

Comment: PHP 5.4 no es muy diferente a la versión 7, considera migrar a la nueva versión.

Comment: Has probado reiniciar el servidor/computadora?

Comment: Si ya hice todo, pero no funciona, desde que actualice sale ese error

Comment: En la barra de tareas, haz clic en el icono de _Wampserver_, luego en tu versión de _PHP_, después en extensiones y verifica que las que deseas activar tengan la marca verde: https://i.stack.imgur.com/etVAE.png

Comment: Ya verifique y están activas